# Notify Aura component of a window.location change

Tags: javascript, aura, event, javascript-controller

It looks like once an aura components (that overrides the New button of a custom object) is loaded and opened, it does not stop running when the user closes it and navigates to other pages. In fact, the IsValid() method still return `true` even thou the users closes the component. The `unrender` function is not executed when the component is aura component is closed.

Is there a way to get an aura component function execute when the user navigates to another record or page?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below event a few years ago to detect url changes.

```
<aura:handler event="aura:locationChange" action="{!c.handleChange}"/>
```

This event is fired whenever the URL is changed in Salesforce.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:locationChange/documentation#!#

But there is this warning in the documentation

> Although aura:locationChange tracks changes to the hash fragment in a
> URL, it’s not useful for tracking navigation with the new URL format.

So you need to test this out and see if it is still working.

While going through the documentation I found another event

```
<aura:handler name="destroy" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleDestroy}"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueDestroy/documentation

I haven't tried this, but you can check this also.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems it only tracks the hash fragment not the url changes